# How to use sed to replace the last occurrence of a string in a file

Tags: sed

I have a text file with the below content:

```
--abcdef12 --  
February April January    
January March January   
January January January   
--abcdef12 --
```

How can I use sed to change the last occurrence of January in the file to July?
Required output:

```
--abcdef12 --  
February April January   
January March January   
January January July  
--abcdef12 --
```

I tried https://linuxhint.com/use-sed-replace-last-occurrence/ - Below was the output:

```
sed '$ s/January/July/' test.txt  
--abcdef12 --  
February April January  
January March January  
January January January  
--abcdef12 --
```

Also tried https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187889/how-do-i-replace-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string-using-sed - Below was the output:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)January/\1July/' test.txt  
--abcdef12 --  
February April July  
January March July   
January January July  
--abcdef12 --
```

I am also curious to know why the above two options do not work!

Comment: `sed` works on a line by line basis, so `sed 's/(.*)January/\1July/' test.txt` finds the last occurrence of `January` on each line. `sed '$ s/January/July/'` searches for `January` on the last line, there is no `January` there. If your `sed` is GNU, use `sed -z 's/\(.*\)January/\1July/' file.txt`.

Comment: Thank you! How to make it inline and update the same file? -i option seems to be not working together with -z.  

sed: -e expression #1, char 42: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: And redirecting using tee or > is giving me an empty file if I use the same file. 
Else I have to save into a temp file and copy it back.

Comment: It is just another adding of an option, `-i`. Just use them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ezi.bak 's/(.*)January/\1July/' input_file
$ cat input_file
--abcdef12 --
February April January
January March January
January January July
--abcdef12 --
```

`-i.bak` creates a backup of the original file with `.bak` extension

```
$ cat input_file.bak
--abcdef12 --
February April January
January March January
January January January
--abcdef12 --
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the `-z` option you can use `tac` for searching the first hit:

```
tac test.txt | sed -r '1,/January/ s/(.*)January/\1July/' | tac
```